# After changing hostname, Ubuntu does not recognize the name

Tags: display-resolution, hostname

After I had changed my hostname through opening a certain file I am unable to remember, I encountered several problems. I was unable to save back-ups, my computer was occasionally unable to identify my graphics card, causing it to be in low resolution mode and terminal did not recognize my hostname.

I dual-boot Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 8, and Windows 8 is able to boot. I am new to Ubuntu. How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Did you edit the file /etc/hostname without making the corresponding change in /etc/hosts? Can you add the contents of those files to your question (e.g. using the cat command like `cat /etc/hostname` and `cat /etc/hosts`)?

Comment: Oh... I was not aware to make changes. I had decided to change my name back to default, since I had found that I was not longer in resolution. If I were to change my hostname, what changes would I make to /etc/hosts/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what file you changed but try the following:

typing in your terminal:

```
hostname
```

will display the current hostname for the system and:

```
sudo hostname a-new-hostname
```

will change the system hostname.